# Macbook Air restart and kernel panic issues

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery, kernel-panic

My Macbook Air 13 running Yosemite 10.10.3 inch doesn't resume from sleep always. Also, there is a `'No batteries Available'` sign frequently and a cross (X) on the battery icon. Also, it doesn't startup/boot properly at times. Here is the stack trace.

```
Anonymous UUID:       1C1E708E-7508-30D3-4B3E-B46EE695A7A0

Sun Jul  5 08:56:28 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8013e17cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f95b8dea5, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000016b2c000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xffffff80204bb000, RBX: 0xffffff80207b7300, RCX: 0xffffff80142c9b40, RDX: 0xffffff7f95b8f080
RSP: 0xffffff80adbbbe10, RBP: 0xffffff80adbbbe20, RSI: 0x0000000000000070, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff802120d570, R9:  0xffffff801ef07e19, R10: 0x000000000000001a, R11: 0x000000000000000a
R12: 0xffffff80207b7390, R13: 0xffffff80207b7300, R14: 0xffffff801f27bd00, R15: 0xffffff80207b7300
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7f95b8dea5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80adbbbac0 : 0xffffff8013d2bda1 
0xffffff80adbbbb40 : 0xffffff8013e17cc2 
0xffffff80adbbbd00 : 0xffffff8013e34b73 
0xffffff80adbbbd20 : 0xffffff7f95b8dea5 
0xffffff80adbbbe20 : 0xffffff7f95b8d67b 
0xffffff80adbbbe70 : 0xffffff80142b3cad 
0xffffff80adbbbeb0 : 0xffffff80142b379f 
0xffffff80adbbbf30 : 0xffffff80142ae553 
0xffffff80adbbbf70 : 0xffffff80142b4443 
0xffffff80adbbbfb0 : 0xffffff8013e125b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU(2.0.7d0)[A80DA941-4E23-36F6-80DA-A1F1A3DD3203]@0xffffff7f95b8c000->0xffffff7f95b90fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f94e02000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[B2340BD5-9422-3EFB-B2DC-1CE74CD852CD]@0xffffff7f94d7c000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013b00000
System model name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 58073918298
last loaded kext at 29685078740: com.intel.kext.intelhaxm   1.1.1 (addr 0xffffff7f963a3000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.1
com.protech.NoSleep 1.4.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.33.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 67
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUART 2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445384533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445384533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

I have tried resetting SMC, PRAM and other troubleshooting.

Kindly help.

Comment: I'd uninstall nosleep and see if it continues to happen.

Comment: I also noticed you are using the "com.intel.kext.intelhaxm" ! I assume you are running the emulator ! http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2bujz2/using_intel_haxm_technology_on_mac_osx_1010/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was caused by the SMC

```
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU

dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily

dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC
```

and the "No batteries Available" would lead me to believe it is the system (SMC) plist file.

Look up your Model ID in the About this Mac. (this is mine)

[image: model]

Now find the plist for your Model ID in the

```
/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/Plugins/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources
```

and move it out to another location.

Restart.

<sub>source: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-solve-kernel_task-high-cpu-usage.1706948/</sub>

Comment: I tried finding it. But it's not there. It only has list upto MacbookAir 4,2. Mine is MacBook Air 6,2

Comment: sorry, my instructions were for Mavericks :(